# C# WPF изменение длины GridViewColumn в GridView как в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

В GridView GridViewColumn горизонтально можно потащить за пределы GridView и покажется горизонтальный ScrollBar

- как это запретить?
- как сделать чтобы Thumb делал другие элементы (GridViewColumn) меньше если "упирать" в Border при скроле а не тащил в ScrollBar (собственно как в DataGrid)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из текста ниче не понял. Есть код? Есть картинки/скриншоты?

Comment: @tym32167 updated

Comment: Пробуйте отключить скролл у GridView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"

Comment: @ValeryLosev не работает